# Can some form extension write to/populate with values from database?

Tags: joomla-3.x, mysql, form

I want to have a very basic form, basically just a couple text fields and a few checkboxes.   Ideally this form would be able to save to a table somewhere with the userid/name of the user that filled it out and the values that they chose. Then the next time the user would go to that page, the form would populate with the values that they chose originally and they would be able to update their selections.

Is there a form extension that is capable of this? fabrik? rsform? chronoform? something else?  I've looked into them a bit and I want to say that is probably possible but I'm not completely sure and I'm curious if anyone knew for a fact.

edit: looks like chronoforms and the 'DB Record Loader' might be what I'm looking for?

Comment: RS Form Pro has this functionality.

Answer (score 1):

RSForms pro have recently added this feature, so because it is a simple form component might fit well to your requirements. But you can definitely create this with Fabrik and Cobalt, or other similar app-builders components, but I guess this will require more work.

Answer (score 1):

ChronoForms is another great forms extension.   RS Forms Pro is fantastic but requires purchase for some of the advanced features/plugins and is geared towards advanced users.   ChronoForms has a better form create wizard with recent update in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

BreezingForms from [Crosstec.de](http://crosstec.de/en/extensions/joomla-forms-download.html) is also able to connect your forms with your Joomla Database. The QuickMode makes it easy to build forms with a series of fields, and you can add your own JavaScript/PHP functions if needed. BreezingForms is not free, but personally I find it a usefull tool for building both simple and advanced forms.

A tutorial on how to integrate a form with your database can be found [here](http://vimeo.com/4207593), and if you want to see how the QuickMode works to build your form you can see [this](http://vimeo.com/57196027) video.